# Java Processbuilder with shared variable

Tags: java, multiprocessing, processbuilder

i'm trying to run 2 processes using Processbuilder.. the thing is **i wonder if it possible to use shared variable for both processes?**

let say i have main_p who create and runs other p1 and p2 processes
and an integer (i) declared in main_p, can i somehow pass the variable reference or make the variable accessible from p1 and p2 at the same time?

main_p

```
 ProcessBuilder pb1 = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", process_1_path, param); 
 Process p1 = pb1.start();
 BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p1.getInputStream()));
 ProcessBuilder pb2 = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", process_2_path, param); 
 Process p2 = pb2.start();
 BufferedReader in2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p2.getInputStream()));
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You're running two Java programs, that you want to communicate - have you considered Threads ?

Comment: i already implement same thing using threads .. but i need to implement it again using multi process

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pipe (via Processes Input/OutputStream) between processes and exchange data using it. Or via a file, or DB or RMI or JMS

Comment: i think this could work if i need to run first Process and when its done then i run the other process and pass the param i retrived from first one using i/o streems.
but i need to run them both at the same time (almost same time)

Comment: i consider using file to share data in case there is no other way :)

Comment: if you start processes like you show in Q then pipe should work